# How to Create a setup file with Database script in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, setup-project

I am trying to make a setup file in C# desktop application project so i use Sql express i want to run the script of the database while install setup file or is there ant way to add the database script inside the setup file to run automatically

Comment: You could create a CustomAction and execute the Script: [Custom Actions Management in Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bbd7cck3(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: i can only add exe and dll only can not execute script files

Comment: Here is a example (see Creating Custom Action Exe): [Install Windows Service using Custom Actions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26091/Install-Windows-Service-using-Custom-Actions)